# Check if at least 2 variables is the same value or higher than another variable

Tags: python

Code:

```
quota = 22

a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
c = int(input("Enter a number: "))
d = int(input("Enter a number: "))
e = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

I would like it so if at least 2 of the variables a - f is equal or higher to the variable quota than print "Quota met"

Preferably I would like it in the most efficient and understandable way.

Comment: Loop over your data, count how many match, check if it is at least 2? This is aside from the fact that it looks like you should be using a list or a container...

Comment: `if [a,b,c,d,e].count(quota) >=2: print('Quota met')`

Comment: [mcve] - what have you already tried?

Comment: You could use a counter variable. Iterate through the input values, if it is equal to `quota` inc the counter. This way you can chack when your counter is at least `2`

Comment: @toonarmycaptain I have not really tried but I have tried to make my code as simple as possible to understand in order to not get any downvotes :)

Comment: @depperm Thanks for the answer but I forgot to add that I would like it to print quota met if at least 2 of the variables are 22 or above. Sorry for the inconvenience, I will edit the question

Comment: "not really trying," and in addition admitting such, is going to get you more downvotes than putting up at least one method you've tried. 
My downvote is withheld primarily out of sympathy for your team losing to Huddersfield :p

Comment: @toonarmycaptain Thanks! I'm not really a big fan tbh. I have changed the question around because I forgot to add something. Could you please help?

Comment: By the way, I would go for `(a,b,c,d,e) = (int(input("Enter a number: ")) for i in range(5))`.

Comment: @Tjaart This seems to work better thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (sum([x >=quota for x in [a,b,c,d,e]])) >= 2: print("Quota met")`

or

`if (sorted([a,b,c,d,e])[-2] >= quota): print("Quota met")`

Comment: Why sum and not just `len` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @danihp `[x >=quota for x in [a,b,c,d,e]]` generates a list of booleans representing whether the corresponding element of the original list is >=2. This list can include both False and True, and both contribute to the length. When you take sum of a list of booleans, False is coerced to 0 and True to 1, and so you get the total number of True. Another option would be to do `[x for x in [a,b,c,d,e] if x >=quota]`, and there you can take the length.

Comment: The second approach is smart. But, in my opinion, both are a bit unreadable (just a bit and in my opinion) I like the approach on your last comment :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann, of course man! Fixed! Thanks a lot. Did you see the typo without test? You are a hero. –

Comment: @danihp I think I saw it without testing but then confirmed it with testing (I pretty much always test before I speak up, just to be sure).

Answer (score 6):

The easiest approach, IMHO, would be to just `count` the number of times `quota` appears there:

```
if (a, b, c, d, e).count(quota) >= 2:
    print "quota met"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I forgot to add that I would like it to print quota met if at least 2 of the variables are 22 or above. Sorry for the inconvenience, I will edit the question.

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you for your contribution but utenngr seems to have answered it! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @birdseyeassassin, this is the right answer for your question. You can't change the question in this way after post it. Jut make another and keep the original one here with this right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a while loop to do the cicle 6 times (and not need for variables)

```
quota = 22
n = 6
res = 0
while n != 0:
  if(int(input("Enter a number: ")) >= quota):
    res += 1
  n -= 1

if(res >= 2):
  print("Quota met")
else:
  print("not met2")
```

or with your method and variables:

```
quota = 22

a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
c = int(input("Enter a number: "))
d = int(input("Enter a number: "))
e = int(input("Enter a number: "))
f = int(input("Enter a number: "))



if (len([x for x in [a,b,c,d,e,f] if x>=quota]) >= 2): print("quota met!")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is way way to complicated and out of my league. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @birdseyeassassin I updated, is this cleaner than the accepted answer, consider try it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann ahhaha yes of course, I completely misunderstood the question at all, check the new edit if you please

Comment: @birdseyeassassin could you try it? remember you can only accept one answer, and vote all you want

Comment: This does seem to work but I found the  other answer more suitable for my skill range. Thanks anyway and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @birdseyeassassin aaah, ok, please take a look at my last big effort, it's very short and easy to read

Comment: I have looked and understood but I find the solution of """f (sum([x >= quota for x in [a,b,c,d,e]])) >= 2:
    print("Quota met") """                                                                                       better but I have still upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an iterable of the entries and sum up the bool value for all items testing equal or above the quota value:

```
if sum(x >= quota for x in (a, b, c, d, e, f)) >= 2:
    print('quota met')
```

Comment: Always short and great Moses my idol, it's a plus one, my answers never get so shorts, take a look if you want. It's a plus one btw

Answer (score 1):

Using [reduce](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce):

> Reduce is a really useful function for performing some computation on a list and returning the result. It applies a rolling computation to sequential pairs of values in a list.

```
In [1]: a,b,c,d,e = 5,6,7,8,9
In [2]: quota=7
In [3]: f=lambda x, y: x + 1 if y >= quota else x
In [4]: reduce ( f, [a,b,c,d,e], 0 )
Out[4]: 3
```

Not really readable but every body loves reduce.

**Edited due @StefanPochmann's comment - function `f` fixed**

Answer (score 0):

```
  quota = 22
cc=0

a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
c = int(input("Enter a number: "))
d = int(input("Enter a number: "))
e = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if (a==quota):
    cc=cc+1
if (b==quota):
    cc=cc+1
if (c==quota):
    cc=cc+1
if (d==quota):
    cc=cc+1
if (e==quota):
    cc=cc+1

if(cc>=2):
    print('Quota met')
else
    print('Quota not met')
```

step 1: get the inputs

step 2: compare every input with quota

step 3: if input match with quota increase the counter(cc) by one

step 4: repeat step 3 for other input

step 5: check the counter if it is greater than or equal to 2 print "Quota met"

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but I have already found my solution. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Make the input calls iterative and test if they are larger than 22. If they are create a boolean list then count how many values are equal or larger than the quota.

```
quota = 22

#create empty list
b_ls = []

# iterate input and check if it's larger than quote
for i in range(5):
  b_ls .append(int(input('Enter a number: ')) >= quota)

# print if quota is meta
if b_ls .count(True) >= 2: print('Quota met')
```

Comment: If you're going to throw the numbers away anyway, you might as well just do `ctr += int(input('Enter a number: ')) >= quota`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have rather collected the input into a list early on:

```
numbers = [int(input("Enter a number: ")) for i in range(5)]
```

The readability would arguably be more simplified, and duplicating `(a,b,c,d,e)` means any future code updates would mean changes need to happen in more than one place.

```
if numbers.count(quota) >= 2: print("Quota met")
```

Comment: I needed the variables as this is part of a much bigger project which needs these variables. Thanks anyway.